# What is 'Local Port from', 'Local Port to', 'Remote Port from' and 'Remote port to' in port forwarding?

Tags: port-forwarding

I'm trying to port forward GTA Online to avoid NAT type problem. It is enabled to strict and I can't find the option to change it to moderate or open in my router page. I have enabled Bridging in my router page. Some of the other sources told to enable UPnP but it wouldn't change my NAT type. Hence I'm trying to port forward and I have created a static IP address but I'm stuck in for what to fill for 'Local Port from', 'Local Port to', 'Remote Port from' and 'Remote port to'.

The TCP ports and UDP ports for GTA Online are:

```
TCP:
UDP: 6672,61455-61458
```

My network is a BSNL Broadband and my modem is Alphion - AONT-1143. This is the image of Port-Forwarding section of my router page:

[image]

Comment: Before doing this, could you check whether the "Status" page actually shows you having a public WAN IP address? Make sure you're not behind CG-NAT, i.e. the WAN address does not start with "10." or "100."

Comment: Um, I couldn't find that but I was able to find something like 'Connection Type' - 'Internet' and the IP address starting with 117 in the status page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPnP wouldn't change the NAT type, but it *would* allow the game itself to create port-forwarding rules.

> I'm stuck in for what to fill for 'Local Port from', 'Local Port to', 'Remote Port from' and 'Remote port to'.

I would guess that the fields are somewhat misnamed:

- "Local port" is the *internal* destination port on your computer (after forwarding),
- "Remote port", then, must mean the *external* destination port on WAN side (before forwarding).
- When the router receives a connection *to* the specified "remote port" it forwards that connection to your computer's "local port".

Each setting has two fields ("from" and "to") because the router allows you to define a *range*, i.e. you could create a single rule with "From: 61455" and "To: 61458" instead of needing four separate rules. (You will still need a separate rule for 6672 however.)

In general, games expect the internal port to be the same as the external one. So you should just enter the same number (or the same range) in both the "Local" and "Remote" columns.

> The TCP ports and UDP ports for GTA Online are:
>
> ```
> TCP:
> UDP: 6672,61455-61458
> ```

This means you'll need two rules:

1. Protocol: UDP, Remote port: from 6672 to 6672, Local port: same
2. Protocol: UDP, Remote port: from 61455 to 61458, Local port: same

Comment: So, the form would be like UDP and 6672 in every blank of Local and Remote ports or it would be like UDP and 61455(from) to 61458(to) in every blank of Local and Remote ports right? I have added them and here is the picture for it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw5lZ.jpg

Comment: Your screenshot looks correct.

Comment: So, how should I test if it's working or not? I have used other website like portchecker something, and it shows me a different IP address, which starts with 117.242.xx.xx, and when I enter the port number 6672, it shows me it is closed. Even if I change the IP address from that 117.242.xx.xx to my static IP, it doesn't show that the ports are open. A very noob doubt, should I run the application in order to check whether the ports are open or anything like that?